# How can I add a legend to my ggplot? Im using geom_line and geom_ribbon

Tags: r, ggplot2

Good afternoon,

I use the following code to generate a plot:

```
ggplot() +
 geom_line(data = disDataHeadItems, aes(x=disDataHeadItems$x, 
 y=disDataHeadItems$Freq)) + 
 geom_line(data = disDataLongTail, aes(x=disDataLongTail$x, 
 y=disDataLongTail$Freq)) +
 xlab("Item id") +
 ylab("# of occurrences") +
 scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(5, 75, 10), expand = c(0, 0)) + 
 scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
 geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0, ymax=disDataHeadItems$Freq, 
 x=disDataHeadItems$x), fill="#CC6666") +
 geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0, ymax=disDataLongTail$Freq, 
 x=disDataLongTail$x), fill="#66CC99") +
 geom_vline(xintercept=19, linetype="dotted")
```

This creates the following plot, which im very happy with :)

[image]
Now I want to add a legend which just indicated that the red part is the top-head items and the green part is the long tail of the data. When I look it up I only find answers that indicate how to alter the legend. But mine just does not show up. Any help is welcome :)

Comment: Any color you specify *outside* your call to aes will not be represented in the legend. Recommend reading a few ggplot tutorials to clarify. You need to put color inside aes brackets for it to appear in the legend.

Comment: Also when mentioning `data=` it is not needed to make a reference to the dataframe when calling the columns so for example; `geom_line(data = disDataHeadItems, aes(x=disDataHeadItems$x, 
 y=disDataHeadItems$Freq))` would be `geom_line(data=disDataHeadItems, aes(x=x, y=Freq))`

Comment: Ah thank you that seemed to fix it, now I can just alter the now existing legend!

Comment: There are a few things you can do to simplify things: one is that `geom_ribbon(ymin = 0, ...)` is equivalent to `geom_area`. Another is that this would benefit from reshaping the data to avoid multiple calls to the same geom. Can you post a sample of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the comments together and adding some random dataframe results in this:

```
library(ggplot2)
disDataHeadItems <- data.frame(
  x = runif(100,1,100),
  Freq = runif(100,5,10)
)
disDataLongTail <- data.frame(
  x = runif(100,1,100),
  Freq = runif(100,5,10)
)

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = disDataHeadItems, aes(x=x, 
                                         y=Freq)) + 
  geom_line(data = disDataLongTail, aes(x=x, 
                                        y=Freq)) +
  xlab("Item id") +
  ylab("# of occurrences") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(5, 75, 10), expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0, ymax=disDataHeadItems$Freq, 
                  x=disDataHeadItems$x, fill="#CC6666")) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0, ymax=disDataLongTail$Freq, 
                  x=disDataLongTail$x, fill="#66CC99")) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=19, linetype="dotted")
```